# How can I replace a string with the output from a command?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Let's say I run `hostname -i` and get the following output:

```
root@linux:/# hostname -i
192.168.1.1
root@linux:/#
```

How would I pipe that output (just the IP address) to replace a certain string in a given file?

I want to (i.e. using `sed` or `awk`) pipe the output of that command to the `my_server_ip` part below:

```
"server":"my_server_ip",
"server_port":8388,
```

Comment: Could you share with us what have you tried so far?

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify if you're trying to replace the literal string `my_server_ip` or trying to replace whatever string is within double quotes after `"server"` or something else.

Comment: Is the document that you want to change the text in a JSON document?  If so, doing it with `jq` is more convenient and safer than with `sed` or `awk`.  Could you possibly show more of the text file that you are working with?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you just want whatever is in quotes after `"server"` changed, not the specific string `my_server_ip`, and if so then using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\("server":"\)[^"]*/\1'"$(hostname -i)"'/' file
"server":"<the host name>",
"server_port":8388,
```

or any awk (more robust if the output of `hostname -i` could contain backreference metachars or sed delimiters, which it shouldn't):

```
$ awk -v h="$(hostname -i)" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} $2=="server"{$4=h} 1' file
"server":"<the host name>",
"server_port":8388,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitution parameter like :  `sed -i -e "s/my_server_ip/$(hostname -i)/" txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU sed, then you can use the `/e` flag to the `s/` command, but the command executed is the whole line:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f
/my_server_ip/{
s//%s/
s/.*/printf '&' $(hostname -i)/e
}
```

This creates a command line that looks like `printf '"server":"%s",' $(hostname -i)` and then executes it, replacing the relevant line.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=$(hostname -i)
sed -i "s/my_server_ip/$m/g" filename
"server":"192.168.1.1",
"server_port":8388,
```